# Finding the number of real roots of an unusual(!) equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

How many real roots does the below equation have?

\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^{2000}}{2001}+2\sqrt{3}x^2-2\sqrt{5}x+\sqrt{3}=0
\end{equation*}

A) 0  B) 11 C) 12 D) 1 E) None of these

I could not come up with anything.

(Turkish Math Olympiads 2001)

Comment: I believe the 2nd derivative is always positive, so inflection never changes, which means you cannot have more than two zeros.  Since two is not a choice, it must be zero or one.

Comment: And it cannot be one because it is an even function.

Comment: @John: Odd, I don't see any even function.

Comment: @user21820 Sorry, not even function, even degree.

Comment: @John Ok but that's wrong too. $x \mapsto x^2$ has only one root.

Comment: @user21820 But it has it twice.

Comment: @John: When asked about number of roots, it has only one. The fact that it is a root with multiplicity 2 does not mean that it has 2 roots. Don't mix the two concepts!

Answer (score 17):

We have that $x^{2000} \geq 0$, because squares are nonnegative.

Further, we have $(x-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}})^2 \geq 0$. This gives $x^2-\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}x+\frac{5}{12} \geq 0$

Therefore $2 \sqrt{3}x^2-2\sqrt{5}x+\frac{10}{12}\sqrt{3} \geq 0$

Therefore $2 \sqrt{3}x^2-2\sqrt{5}x+\sqrt{3} > 0$

Therefore $\frac{x^{2000}}{2001} + 2 \sqrt{3}x^2-2\sqrt{5}x+\sqrt{3} > 0$

Therefore there are no real roots.

Comment: Nice Solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** $2\sqrt{3} x^2 - 2\sqrt{5} x + \sqrt{3}$ is positive and has no roots.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the discriminant of $f(X) = 2\sqrt{3}x^2-2\sqrt{5}x+\sqrt{3}=0$:

$$(-2\sqrt{5})^2 - 4(2\sqrt{3})\sqrt{3} = 20 - 24 < 0.$$

Therefore $f(x)$ has no real roots.
But $f(0) = \sqrt{3} > 0$, so $f(x) > 0$ everywhere.

Now combine this with $$\frac{x^{2000}}{2001} \geq 0.$$